# How do I prevent MMQGIS from escaping the carriage returns inside my fields?

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth, html, mmqgis

I style my maps inside qgis then export them to KML using the mmqgis tool to be viewed on Google Earth.

When I do this, I use MMQGIS's "Custom HTML" option for styling the display of fields in the descriptions for polygons. There's only one problem: one of my fields contains several newlines. When I load the file on Google Earth, the new lines are always escaped. I've tried to go back and edit the field data, swapping out the `'\n'` for `'<br/>'` in addition to a few different other things like `'&#xA;'` or `'<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>'`.

All of these things do the same thing essentially. Every program but Google Earth views them as having new lines. Is there any way to format my text and/or change some settings so that MMQGIS and/or Google Earth won't escape my new lines?

Comment: Using `<br/>` instead of `\n` should be the right way so I would continue to test that path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854377/how-can-i-make-multi-line-label-on-google-maps-when-using-chrome. But first I suggest to search if Google Earth supports multiline labels at all. Or do you know that it does?

Comment: I don't think Google Earth supports multi-line labels on the map.  When I put a <br> tag into the "name" field of a placemark, the tag shows up in the one-line label, but it makes a newline in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Earth does not support multi-line labels at all. You have done right things with MMQGIS and using `<br/>` is what is recommended for example in the answers to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854377/how-can-i-make-multi-line-label-on-google-maps-when-using-chrome. However, Google Earth does not split the label.

[image]

Comment: Not trying to put new lines into the labels themselves, I’m trying to get them to be expressed inside of fields in the description. You know, what shows up after you click on it

Comment: Would you mind to edit your question and include that information? Also an example about the .kml file as you have it now would be useful.

Comment: If you think that my first trial to answer was not useful just tell it and I will delete this posting.

Comment: My computer is not currently functioning due to an ongoing kernel panic. I’ve updated the question to be more specific about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that Google Earth supports can be found by creating a placemark with Google Earth itself. For example by using these texts from the user interface

Name:

```
Name<br/>Second line
```

Description:

```
First line
Second line
```

are stored into KML file that GE writes as

```
    <Placemark>
        <name>Name&lt;br/&gt;Second line</name>
        <description>First line 
Second line</description>
```

Notice that there is a linefeed character [LF] in the description as can be seen in this screen capture from a text editor.

[image]

I am not sure if this is valid XML but at least it is what Google Earth writes. However, the Name line gives a hint about an alternative way. The KML file edited this way shows both the Name and Description on two lines in the Google Earth pop-up.

```
<Placemark>
<name>Name&lt;br/&gt;Second line</name>
<description>First line&lt;br/&gt;Second line</description>
```

[image]