# Break KML nametag with new line

Tags: google-maps, kml

I would like to break the KML name-tag into several lines when showing it as a label.
E.g I would like:

`<name>Germany Deutschland Tyskland</name>`

to be shown as a label in the map like:

Germany
Deutschland
Tyskland

not

Germany Deutschland Tyskland

How can I do that?

Comment: Try XML entities ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504890/how-to-add-a-newline-line-break-in-an-xml-file

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442421/how-do-i-prevent-mmqgis-from-escaping-the-carriage-returns-inside-my-fields about how to break the name. Notice also that Google Earth does not split the name on the map, only in the pop-up.